# ¿Cómo mostrar información de archivos individuales desde un tabs dinamicamente usando ajax load?

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo el siguiente diseño de un `tabs` vertical:

```js
$(function () {
 $(".tab-content").hide();
 $("ul.tabs-list li:first").addClass("active-tab").show();
 //Folling line changed to support multi tabs
 $(".tabs-container .tab-content:first-child").show();
 $("ul.tabs-list span").click(function(){
  $("ul.tabs-list li").removeClass("tab-active");
  $(this).parent("li").addClass("tab-active");
  var activeTab = $(this).attr("data-target");
  $(activeTab).siblings(".tab-content").hide();
  $(activeTab).fadeIn();
  return false;
 });
});
```

```css
.vertical-tab {
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1140px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

ul.tabs-list {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 150px;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 display: flex;
 border-bottom: solid 1px #EAEAEA;
}
.tab-item {
 color: #898d98;
 font-size: .875em;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 list-style: none;
 /*border-bottom: solid 1px #FFFFFF;*/
 outline: none;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 text-transform: capitalize;
}
.tab-item span, .tab-item span:visited, .tab-item span:active, .tab-item span:hover {
 text-decoration:none;
 color: #898d98;
 list-style: none;
 /*padding: 0 1.1em .4em;*/
 padding: 0.8em 1.1em 0.8em 1.1em;
 display:inline-block;
 font-size: 1.5em;
}
.tab-item span:hover{
 border-bottom: solid 1px #3E9CCA;
}
.tab-active {
 text-shadow: none;
 /*background-color: #f9f9f9ed;*/
 border-bottom: solid 1px #3E9CCA;
}
.tab-active span {
 color: #1ca0de;
}
.tabs-container {
 padding: 0px;
 clear: left;
 border-top: none;
 background: none;
}
.tab-content {
 /*margin: 1em 0 0 0;
 border-bottom: solid 1px #EAEAEA;
 padding-bottom: 1em;*/
 padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 60px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
  <div class="vertical-tab">
   <!-- Menú de opciones -->
   <ul class="tabs-list">
    <li class="tab-item active-tab tab-active">
     <span data-target="#1">Anuncio</span>
    </li>
    <li class="tab-item">
     <span data-target="#2">Tareas</span>
    </li>
   </ul>
   <!-- //END -->
   <div class="tabs-container">
    <div id="1" class="tab-content tab-content-active" style="">
     <div class="tab-content">
      <!-- Mostrar información-->
            <span>1</span>
      <div id="#divTabs"></div>
      <!-- // End Tab Content One -->
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="2" class="tab-content" style="display: none;">
     <div class="tab-content">
      <span>2</span>
      <!-- Mostrar información-->
      <div id="#divTabs"></div>
      <!-- // End Tab Content Two -->
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Estuve buscando información referente al mismo, encontré que se puede obtener información mediante el uso de `.load(file)` encontré esto:

```
function show_tab(tab){
    //var data = $( "#" ).serialize();
    //var url = '.php?tab=' + tab;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data
    }).done(function(resp){
        tab = parseInt(tab);
        var dataTarget = parseInt(resp.dataTarget);
        switch(dataTarget) {
            case 1:
                urlphp = 'file1.php'
            break;
            case 2:
                urlphp = 'file2.php'
            break;
            case 3:
                urlphp = 'file3.php'
            break;
            default:
                urlphp = 'file1.php'
            break;
        }

        $('#divTabs').load(urlphp,function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
            if(statusTxt === "success") {
                $('.tab').css( "display", "none" );
                $('#tab'+ tab).fadeIn("slow");
            }

            if(statusTxt === "error") {
                //
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Hasta donde logre entender la información se muestra mediante un `<div id="#divTabs"></div>` según la opción escogida, lo que también significa que sería innecesario crear varios `<div id="2" class="tab-content" style="display: none;">` para mostrar la información, bastaría solo con uno porque la información que se recibe es mediante un `<div id="#divTabs"></div>`.

¿Cómo puedo mostrar la información según el tabs seleccionado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a modificar un poco lo que tenés hecho porque hay varios errores. Asumo que lo que querés hacer es cargar el contenido de `fileX.php` dentro del `#divTabs` correspondiente al tab clickeado.

Si la URL a cargar depende del tab, por qué no definirla directamente en el HTML? Por otro lado, no podes tener `IDs` duplicados (`#divTabs`).

Me parece que estás usando `.active-tab.tab-active` al mismo tiempo en `.tab-item` pero solo hace algo el `.tab-active`.

**HTML:**

- Agregué `data-url=""` con la `URL` del archivo.
- Reemplacé los `id="#divTabs"` por clases.
- Se podría borrar el `style="display: none;` y hacer cambios en el `CSS`.

```
<div class="vertical-tab">
    <!-- Menú de opciones -->
    <ul class="tabs-list">
        <li class="tab-item tab-active">
            <span data-target="#1" data-url="file1.php">Anuncio</span>
        </li>
        <li class="tab-item">
            <span data-target="#2" data-url="file2.php">Tareas</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- //END -->
    <div class="tabs-container">
        <div id="1" class="tab-content tab-content-active" style="">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <!-- Mostrar información-->
                <span>1</span>
                <div class="divTabs"></div>
                <!-- // End Tab Content One -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="2" class="tab-content" style="display: none;">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <span>2</span>
                <!-- Mostrar información-->
                <div class="divTabs"></div>
                <!-- // End Tab Content Two -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

- La línea `$(".tab-content").hide();` la podrías borrar y ocultar por defecto desde `CSS`.
- `$("ul.tabs-list li:first").addClass("tab-active").show();` el `show()` al final no se que hace, porque el `li` no está oculto.

```
$(".tab-content").hide();
$("ul.tabs-list li:first").addClass("tab-active").show(); // Acá decía "active-tab"

// Folling line changed to support multi tabs
$(".tabs-container .tab-content:first-child").show();
$("ul.tabs-list span").click(function(){
    $("ul.tabs-list li").removeClass("tab-active");
    $(this).parent("li").addClass("tab-active");
    var activeTab = $(this).attr("data-target");
    $(activeTab).siblings(".tab-content").hide();
    $(activeTab).fadeIn();

    // Carga el archivo
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    $(activeTab).find('.divTabs').load(url);
});
```

Comment: Hola @azeós gracias por su respuesta, me podrías explicar cómo se cargan los archivos, como lo identifica al hacer clic en las opciones del tabs, simplemente debo agregar todos los fieles que tenga en `var url = $(this).data('url');` pero no veo nada que lo identifique es decir si el archivo `file3.php` quiero que se muestre en la opción 1 y el `file2.php` se muestre en la segunda opción.

Comment: Volvé a leer mi respuesta, eso está definido en el código `HTML` en el `data-url` de cada tab.

Comment: Yo pensé que las rutas se iban agrega en el código `javascript = urlphp = 'file1.php' `

Comment: @Lily podrías agregar las rutas en el archivo js, pero es menos práctico y menos reutilizable. Si quisieras utilizar el mismo código para otros tabs que cargan otros archivos, no podrías. De esta manera, al tener definidos los archivos en el código HTML, el JS se mantiene siempre igual.

Comment: @Lily pudiste probar el código?